# Executing sed from docker-compose

Tags: bash, sed, docker-compose

I am trying to execute a sed command from a docker compose file. The command is looking to match some text in a file and then replace the next line of text with the text 
The command I am executing is:

```
 command: bash -c "sed ''/Http Basic Authentication Filter/!b;n;c<filter>'' webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml > webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/noauth.xml"
```

I can run the command directly in bash and it works as expected however running docker-up I get:

```
sed: unmatched '/'
bash: n: command not found
bash: filter: No such file or directory
```

So I'm assuming this is a YAML character escaping issue but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I have also tried the following to avoid having to escape characters:

```
    command: > 
     bash -c sed '/Http Basic Authentication Filter/!b;n;c<filter>' webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml > webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/noauth.xml
```

Comment: Is it supposed to have `''` ? Shouldn't they just be `'` ?

Comment: They have to be escaped in a YML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quotes inside of double quotes.  The double single quotes (sic) are passed through verbatim, producing `/Http` as the first string `sed` sees, which obviously lacks a closing slash.

YAML quoting would require doubled single quotes if the string was enclosed in single quotes; but you used double quotes, so a single quote in the value does not need escaping (and trying will effectively result in no quotes after the shell removes adjacent pairs of empty quotes).